# PWA manifest.json - "theme_color" and "background_color" not working, splash screen not showing on android device

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, create-react-app, manifest.json, progressive-web-apps

When I look at the manifest.js in Chrome DevTools I can see that the logo and colors are there. However, when I start the website from my homescreen on my android device, neither the background or theme color is loaded, nor my splash screen is shown.
Any idea why?

Manifest.json:

```
{
  "short_name": "Example",
  "name": "Example",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "images/logo_192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "images/logo_512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#a300c4",
  "background_color": "#c46a00"
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: Manifest in Chrome Devtools]

**EDIT**

I found the mistake. I was browsing the website via a remote device using the Chrome DevTools. Port-forwarding to localhost:3000 doesn't match the https requirement for the splash screen to get triggered.

Now the pwa starts in standalone mode, the colors and the splash screen are shown correctly.

**However**, the splash screen logo is not shown and I have no idea why.
The path to the image is correct and the image exists with the correct filename and type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue with the splash screen was? Having the same issue.

Comment: It's been a long time, but I think it was just a stupid mistake made by me.
The PNG Images had the wrong sizes. I thought I exported them as 512x512px but when a checked them, they were like 499x501 or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only thing I see wrong with this manifest is start URL. Change it to something like below

```
  "start_url": "/index.html",
```

or

```
  "start_url": "https://example.com/myapp/",
```

If this didn't help, please host your app in some public domain and share the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the solution was indeed hosting the app on a live server instead of just browsing it via localhost.
However, the splash screen image is still not shown. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 19):

"If you page already has a theme-color meta tag — for example `<meta name="theme-color" content="#2196F3">` — then the page level configuration will be used instead of the value in the manifest."

from: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-manifest-to-set-sitewide-theme-color

Comment: I'm in the process of converting an Angular application to a PWA. The Angular CLI adds the `<meta name="theme-color">` tag automatically, so this was the solution for me. I needed to update my manifest AND `index.html`. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score -2):

Change the following:

`"background_color": "#c46a00"` and `"background-color": "#ffffff"`

Comment: the underscored `background_color` is correct in this case since this is from a `browserconfig.xml` file, **not** an html style attribute such as `background-color`